# how to return a value to the main function after clicking a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, events, button, tkinter

In this file, I tried to return the value of `employNum` and `employPass` to the main function each time I clicked the display button. How can I do that?

```
from tkinter import *

def displayButton(root,employNum, employPass):

    Label(root,text = employNum.get() ).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)
    Label(root, text = employPass.get()).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = N+S+W+E)


def main():

    root = Tk()

    Label(root, text = 'Employee Number: ').grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = 'Login Password: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

    employeeNum = StringVar()
    employeePass = StringVar()
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeeNum).grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    Entry(root, textvariable = employeePass).grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    checkButton = BooleanVar()
    Checkbutton(root, text = 'Remember Me', variable = checkButton).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    Button(root, text = 'Save', relief = RAISED).grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = E)
    display = Button(root, text = 'Display', relief = RAISED, command = lambda: displayButton(root, employeeNum,employeePass))
    display.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky = E)

    Label(root, text = "Employee's number is ").grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
    Label(root, text = "Employee's Passowrd is ").grid(row =4 , column = 0, sticky = W)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Button can't return value using `return`. You can only set value in **global** variable or passed as argument. You can change text in `Label` assigned to **global** variable or passed as argument. You can create new `Label` but `root` have to be **global** variable or passed as argument.